# How to check 1 to 1 relationship in Oracle(in one table)

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table with many columns, but only two of them are important to me. I want to check for the 1 to 1 relationship between col1 and col2(and if col1 exists more then one record of col2 it must be shown). Here is my sql query:

```sql
select tbl1.col1, count(tbl1.col1)
  from admin.table_1 tbl1
  left join ( select col2,col1 from admin.table_1) tbl2
    on tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1 and tbl1.col2 = tbl2.col2
 group by tbl1.col1
having count(tbl1.col1) >1;
```

Is my calculation correct? Maybe it can be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check there is one `col2` for each `col1` and the reflexive relationship that there is one `col1` for each `col2`. You can perform these checks using an analytic `COUNT` function:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 ( col1, col2 ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 4 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2
FROM   (
  SELECT col1,
         col2,
         COUNT( col1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY col2 ) AS col1_per_col2,
         COUNT( col2 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY col1 ) AS col2_per_col1
  FROM   table_1
)
WHERE  col1_per_col2 > 1
OR     col2_per_col1 > 1;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> COL1 | COL2
> ---: | ---:
>    2 |    2
>    2 |    3
>    4 |    4
>    5 |    4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0b3b504d612404354cd5bf333b6e01ca)*

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the `group by` as following:

```
SELECT
    TBL1.COL1,
    COUNT(1)
FROM
    ADMIN.TABLE_1 TBL1
GROUP BY
    TBL1.COL1
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT TBL1.COL2) > 1;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` :

```
select tbl1.col1, count(tbl1.col1)
  from admin.table_1 tbl1 
 where exists ( select 1 
                  from admin.table_1 tbl2 
                 where tbl2.col1 = tbl1.col2 )
 group by tbl1.col1                  
having count(tbl1.col1)>1
```